# Streaming an MP3 on stdout to Jplayer using PHP

Tags: php, header, streaming, stdout, jplayer

I'm initializing jplayer with the following parameters:

```
$jplayer.jPlayer('setMedia',{
  mp3: data.audioMP3,
  oga: data.audioOGA
});
```

Assume that `data.autdioMP3` (and it's OGA counterpart) are paths to a php script, for example: `'http://myserver.local/playaudio.php?songID=99&format=mp3'`

Where I am struggling is with `playaudio.php`. I would like to read the MP3 file and stream it to jplayer without revealing the path to the audio (this is why I am not initializing jplayer with a path to the audio file).

Something like (taken partially from [the example for readfile](http://th.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) at php docs):

```
<?php

$if ($validUser && file_exists($file){
     header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
     header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
     ob_clean();
     flush();
     readfile($file);
     exit;
}
?>
```

I think this just forces the download of the file though... will this still reveal the path to the file to the user? Is there a better option to stream raw mp3 data to the user without revealing the path to the file that you know of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's answers.

I actually ended up solving the problem without revealing the path to the audio file to the user.

Because this is for an online voice messaging application, it was important to protect the path to the messages in order to protect the user's privacy.

The situation ended up being further complicated by the fact that the messages are stored on a remote server... found this out right after I posted this question.

So all in all the process was:

1) Curl the MP3 file from the remote server

2) Set some headers to force the download of the data, which you then echo to stdout

Because the data is being put on standard out and the headers are set to force a download, the effect for jPlayer is the same as if it had requested a file at /some/dir/message.mp3, except that the request goes to /some/dir/playmessage.php - thus the path is never revealed to the user.

EDIT** - **Assume that I have access control, validation running before the snippit below, otherwise exposing the path to the script below is no different than just exposing the path to the mp3. (see comments between me and Lloyd)**

Here's the code that ended up getting the job done:

```
$ch = curl_init($remoteFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($data === false) {
  echo 'CURL Failed';
  exit;
}

//Get file size
if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];
}

//force user to download file contents
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . $contentLength);
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $data;
exit;
?>
```

Assume that `$remoteFile` is a path to the mp3 file that I want to play on the server where we are storing messages.

I found this resource on [reading a remote file using PHP](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx) especially helpful. Here's some more information on [modifying http headers](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm).

**NOTE** I am essentially downloading the file twice, which slows the process down for the user. There is probably a better way to do this. :) If you kept the file locally, what I had initially in my question actually works (using readfile() to output the raw mp3 data).

Comment: is it just the *filename* you must conceal from the user? if you are using jPlayer to play a media file then the path to file played will be revealed in Firefox/Chrome/Safari/IE9 Developer Tools. Whether the path is `/some/dir/message.mp3` or `/some/dir/playmessage.php` makes no difference - it is still a URL to media which can be freely accessed and downloaded.. I don't consider your solution private..

Comment: Hi lloyd, Thanks for your feedback. I've tested it in both firebug and developer tools and it does conceal the path to the mp3. 

Basically what happens is this: 

1) The php script curls the mp3 file as binary data into a variable

2) the php script sets the headers to force a download

3) the php script puts binary data onto stdout, and because of the headers, jplayer treats the response data it gets from the php file as if it were downloading an mp3 file (which it is, essentially). The path curl uses to the original mp3 is no more visable than any other php variable you don't output.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying now... yes - it is just the path to the mp3 file name that I must protect due to the architecture of the application. That they have the path to the php script is ok, because I have authentication built in here that will only output the mp3 data to certain users.

Comment: ahh, i see.. you have access-control on `playmessage.php`- you should have said! Glad you are sorted.. speak soon.

Comment: Good point, a bit confusing... edited my answer to be more explicit. Thanks!

Comment: in the end, my answer was appropriate! (suggesting oAuth or Access Control)

Comment: Thanks looking for something similiar going to try this I think Facebook does this for their music player as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using javascript to get the file, others can do the same by reading the headers/file requests from the browser (firebug, Chrome's default tools, etc).

The best way to protect your files from being downloaded is to make a series of checks to get at the data. It's not perfect, but it will deter all but the most determined. For some ideas, check out this page on [Grooveshark's API](http://nettech.wikia.com/wiki/Grooveshark_Internal_API) (This is a bit old and some info is missing, so it's the perfect reference), or just visit Grooveshark/Youtube and see how they protect their content.

It is possible to recreate this kind of security with some clever usage of sessions and a good database.

Answer (score 2):

i think you'll struggle to prevent users discovering your media content URL, i'd say it was pretty much impossible (a quick look at the 'Network' tab on Chrome would reveal your loaded track, regardless how you coded `playaudio.php`).

I'd say you were better off sticking to publishing media you don't mind sharing with the world.. Or just publish

- A *n* second preview
- A lesser quality version, e.g. 90bps / Mono

If you really wanted to protect your resources, you could use oAuth or Access Control at the server side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's for a client, it's a voice messaging service. So, it's important that the messages be protected to protect user privacy. :)

Comment: You can see my answer below for an easy way to hide the path of the message from the user.