# How to stream an audio file without be downloadable and hiding the original file name/address?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming

I need to stream audio files from my server, but I no want that:

- the content is "*savable*" on the user's PC (I mean the user shouldn't
  download the file and save it on his PC, due Copyright issues)
- the address & name of the original file, shouldn't be revealed.

I tried the interesting solution here proposed:

[Streaming an MP3 on stdout to Jplayer using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753301/streaming-an-mp3-on-stdout-to-jplayer-using-php/29109634?noredirect=1#comment46449423_29109634)

I created a file called ***music.php*** with the proposed code.

after have called the script music.php, calling it from the URL bar of any browser, it appears the multimedia reader. The play starts excellently.

Then just right click and ***save as...*** and it saves a file called music.php

But the content of this file, is the audio file itself. Thus just renaming it into *music.mp3* and I downloaded the original MP3 :-/ which is what I no want it occurs.

Please, do you have any suggestion?

Thank ou so much

Answer (score 0):

> but I no want that:  the content is "savable" on the user's PC

This isn't possible.  If you can play it, you can record and save it.

> the address & name of the original file, shouldn't be revealed

Why?  If you offer a script for downloading the file, then you can download that just as easily.  If your intention is to prevent folks from directly linking to files, then you can check the `Referer` header to ensure that the request came from your site.  However, anyone could still download the files if they wanted to by not sending that header.

You might also consider how signed URLs for Amazon S3 work.  HMAC is used to create a signed URL that expires after a certain period of time.  The URL works, but only if the application granted access for the user to use it, and only for a few minutes or whatever you specify.  In your case, simple session data could help if you are only allowing signed in users to get at your music.  Your question doesn't say entirely what you're trying to do, so what works in your case is up to you.

> But the content of this file, is the audio file itself. Thus just renaming it into music.mp3 and I downloaded the original MP3 :-/ which is what I no want it occurs.

Again, that isn't something you can prevent.  Even if you go way out of your way to write your own streaming methods and use the Web Audio API or whatever to play it, it's still trivial to capture that data or even record the audio digitally.

Comment: Hi Brad,
The goal is: to make the user able to listen to the file, but to  avoid he downloads it. Because the music is on selling on iTunes and it doesn't cost a fortune.

The method I would like to apply, but i have not clue how, it's similare to the one on Reverbnation.
I can't find their files nor download them. As far as I don't use special programs to record the stream, as you also told.
The solution of the temporary URL (Token?) it's quite interesting. I need to develop something or to find some documentation to see if there is already something ready or if I have to start from scratch